# Is there any specific method to run / execute external SQL file(s) directly from file system in Oracle 12c SQL PLUS command line?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

I am a regular user of MYSQL & have recently started learning SQL & PL/SQL in Oracle EE Database 12c.
I am trying to set-up sample employee , departments, ... tables for learning purpose. I have the SQL files to create schema, create tables * populate tables SQL files in my file system.

I know the `\. <path to SQL file>` command in MYSQL to load & run external scripts. So I wish to know, Does any such method exists in Oracle SQL plus command line?

Comment: Maybe you should [consult the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e18404/ch_five.htm#i1210918) to familiarise yourself with how SQL*Plus works. It might be worth looking through [the concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/toc.htm) to see what's different.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@` to run external scripts in SQL Plus. Type @ followed by directory location and file name.
Example:

```
SQL> @ C:\sample_query.sql;
```